# AttributeError: 'Anonymousidentity' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, web-applications, web, flask

everyone! I'm using Flask to build a website. But when I open 127.0.0.1:5000, it returns  AttributeError: 'Anonymousidentity' object has no attribute 'name'. Anonymousidentity is defined in flask.ext.principal. I have read the flask-principal/**init**.py where anonymousidentity defined, there is no attribute 'name',neither in class 'Identity'.

I am a beginner and have no idea where the problem is. May someone could help me, any suggestion is also appreciated! :)

Here are the account/service.py . The error occurs in def current_user(identity=None), return models.User.query.get(identity.name)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from flask import current_app, g, render_template
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from flask.ext.principal import identity_changed, identity_loaded
from flask.ext.principal import Identity, AnonymousIdentity
from flask.ext.principal import RoleNeed, UserNeed

from ..extensions import db, mail
from ..permissions import roles
from . import models, account


get_appobj = lambda: current_app._get_current_object()


# -------------------------------
# Login and Logout (Authenticate)
# -------------------------------

def login(user):
    """User login."""
    identity_changed.send(get_appobj(), identity=Identity(user.id))


def logout():
    """User logout."""
    identity_changed.send(get_appobj(), identity=AnonymousIdentity())


def current_user(identity=None):
    identity = identity or g.identity
    return models.User.query.get(identity.name)


@account.app_context_processor
def account_context_processor():
    return {'current_user': current_user}


@identity_loaded.connect
def on_identity_loaded(sender, identity):
    """Load the roles for identity user."""
    user = current_user(identity)
    if user:
        identity.provides.add(UserNeed(user.id))
        identity.provides.add(roles.login)
        if user.is_actived:
            identity.provides.add(roles.authenticated)
        if user.is_admin:
            identity.provides.add(roles.admin)
        if user.is_branch:
            identity.provides.add(roles.branch)


# ------------------------------
# Sign Up and Email Confirm User
# ------------------------------

def send_confirm_mail(user):
    """Send a confirm mail for signing up user."""
    if user.is_actived:
        raise models.UserAcitvedError(user)  # only provide for unactived user

    with user.permissions['send_confirm_mail'].require(403):
        message = Message("grasu",
                          sender="no-reply@grasu.edu.cn",
                          recipients=[user.email])
        message.html = render_template("mail/activeuser.html",
                                       userid=user.id,
                                       token=user.active_token)
        mail.send(message)


def signup(user):
    """Sign up a user."""
    # check unique
    users = models.User.query
    identity_existed = users.filter_by(email=user.email).count()
    nickname_has_been_used = users.filter_by(nickname=user.nickname).count()
    if identity_existed:
        raise IdentityExistedError
    if nickname_has_been_used:
        raise NicknameUsedError

    # write into database
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

    # login and send mail
    login(user)
    send_confirm_mail(user)


# ----------
# Exceptions
# ----------

class IdentityExistedError(Exception):
    """User's email has existed in database."""


class NicknameUsedError(Exception):
    """User's nickname has been used."""
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed there is no `name` attribute. Instead use the `id` attribute.

```
return models.User.query.get(identity.id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also found this problem. Because the venv
on the server depends on flask-principal-2.0, and the venv on my computer depends on flask-principal-3.5. :)